# Como grabar con opencv, un video al que se le sustrajo el fondo? en Python

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This program shows how to use background subtraction methods provided by \
                                              OpenCV. You can process both videos and images.')
parser.add_argument('--input', type=str, help='Path to a video or a sequence of image.', default='vtest.avi')
parser.add_argument('--algo', type=str, help='Background subtraction method (KNN, MOG2).', default='MOG2')
args = parser.parse_args()

## [create]
#create Background Subtractor objects
if args.algo == 'MOG2':
    backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
else:
    backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()
## [create]

## [capture]
capture = cv.VideoCapture('latex_3mum_randomwalk_0_recorte.avi')
if not capture.isOpened():
    print('Unable to open: ' + args.input)
    exit(0)
## [capture]
ancho = int(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
alto = int(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
 
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object.The output is stored in 'outpy.avi' file.
out = cv.VideoWriter('outpy.avi',cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 10, (ancho,alto))
 
while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    ## [apply]
    #update the background model
    fgMask = backSub.apply(frame)
    ## [apply]
    

    ## [display_frame_number]
    #get the frame number and write it on the current frame
    cv.rectangle(frame, (10, 2), (100,20), (255,255,255), -1)
    cv.putText(frame, str(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)), (15, 15),
               cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5 , (0,0,0))
    ## [display_frame_number]

    ## [show]
    #show the current frame and the fg masks
    frame=cv.resize(frame, (660, 540))
    fgMask = cv.resize(fgMask, (660, 540))
    cv.imshow('Frame', frame)
    cv.imshow('FG Mask', fgMask)
    ## [show]
    if ret == True: 
     
    # Write the frame into the file 'output.avi'
        out.write(fgMask)
 
    # Display the resulting frame    
        cv.imshow('grabado',fgMask)
    
 
    # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
 
    keyboard = cv.waitKey(30)
    if keyboard == 'q' or keyboard == 27:
        break

 
# When everything done, release the video capture and video write objects
capture.release()
out.release()

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Este es el código del cual dispongo, en donde tengo grabado un movimiento browniano de partículas de látex, por lo que tengo que sacarle el fondo y quedarme con el video resultante. La parte de sacarle el fondo funciona, pero la parte de guardar el video andaría con problemas, al terminar de ejecutar el código, cuando intento entrar al archivo.avi generado no abre y pesa unos pocos kb lo cual me hace pensar que solo creo el archivo pero no guardo nada en el.

El problema debe estar dentro del while(creo)